# Can I post to a facebook users feed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I think this used to be possible, and I was trying to update some code, but it does not appear that I can post to the me/feed endpoint using version 11 of the Graph API, Is this correct? Or is there another way to do this that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging, it does not appear to be possible anymore. So much for automations in that context. :(

Comment: It was removed, because it created way too much spam. Letting users actively share content from your site/app is still possible, and more “automation” should really not be needed, for personal profiles.